# Can't see the data in emulator DDMS of android Eclipse

Tags: android

I have been trying to create the app with sqlite db using cordova-2.9.0. I can't see the  //data/data/  in emulator DDMS of android Eclipse.

Could anybody guide to me.

thanks and regards
brite

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to bring up the File Explorer View from the Android View options.

Window -> Show View -> Android -> File Explorer.

And then, go to the Devices View and select the device from the list. (You should see the device in this screen if it's connected in Debug mode)